# ¿Cómo solucionar el Error al crear APK en Reac-Native "Gradle build failed with unknown error."?

Tags: react-native

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este error me sale al intentar construir el APK de mi app.
Me gustaría saber si alguien lo ha podido solucionar. Gracias!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.